# IOT data in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, publish, google-cloud-pubsub

I am able to establish a connection between my IOT device and google cloud. When I run the program the API's are getting hit and I could see the changes in the API overview graph.

I am trying to push my data through mqtt connection. I am not able to see the data in the cloud/ I am not sure if I am successful in this operation. 
Is there any Pub/sub service I should enable before doing this operation? Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

IOT Core is essentially a  Pub/Sub with MQTT management.   To do anything with the data you need to have something subscribed to the IOT instance you have created.  You can do this pretty simply by creating a CloudFunction that is subscribe to your IOT instance.  You can put some logs in there to make sure you're seeing what is coming through.  There are a lot of good examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's an awful lot of ways you could answer that.  If all you want to do is see the data that is being stored you could:

- Write it to BigQuery, super cheap way to store and query a lot of data.
- Write it to DataStore you could then create a App Engine application for displaying the data.